# SWRevealViewController not toggle with swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I was using the code with swift 2.1

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"

            view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }
```

And now, I'm using `Swift3` with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }
```

The codes with the version 2.1 works perfect, but in action `revealToggle` is not executed in `swift3`.

Someone has an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm having same issue, just like you described...

Comment: I end up using a different library to achieve side menu functionality: https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController/. It's available on CocoaPods and best of all written in Swift 3.

Comment: Finally, I decided to use: [https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution for SWRevealViewController in Swift 3:

```
    if revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector((SWRevealViewController.revealToggle) as (SWRevealViewController) -> (Void) -> Void) // Swift 3 fix
        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Hello bro Pro, I try with your code. My problem is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573338/swrevealviewcontroller-button-not-work-after-clicking-back-button-from-another-v. After I tried with your code, the left menu does not show and it goes to home view controller.

Comment: Hi May Phyu, did you try the solution above for Swift 3? This solution is only for Swift 3. Also, did you try the third line of code above exactly as shown?

Comment: This answer possible for ButtonAction?

Comment: @MangiReddy Hi, it should be possible though i havent tired with Button.

Comment: @Pro not possible for a button. I tried but not worked for me.